# Add/Delete dynamic rows to HTML Table

Tags: asp.net

I am creating dynamic accordion pane and each pane has dynamic table with different id and buttons, in some pane i wanted to add dynamic rows to html table, i am using below code to perform this activity,

$('#myTable tr:last').after('1a');

i am not able to add any rows, my problem is how do i link this with dynamic button and dynamic table.

any suggestion or valuable comment would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $("#myTable tr:last").after($("<tr><td>hello</td></tr>"));
 $("#myTable tr:last").remove();
```

and what's your problem?you need confirm which a table to add new row?if yes,you need do something like this(monitor which the panel trigger add row event)

HTML:

```
<div id="panel1><table></table><input value="add row" /></div>
```

js

```
$("#panel1 input").bind("click", function () {
    $("tr:last", $(this).parent("div")).after($("<tr><td>hello</td></tr>"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create  javascript function  to add/delete dynamic rows to HTML Table.

Try this one.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {

var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "checkbox";
cell1.appendChild(element1);

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element2 = document.createElement("input");
element2.type = "text";
cell3.appendChild(element2);

}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
try {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
var row = table.rows[i];
var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
table.deleteRow(i);
rowCount--;
i--;
}

}
}catch(e) {
alert(e);
}
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="250px" border="1">
<TR>
<TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
<TD> 1 </TD>
<TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I am creating buttons and other control in code behind file i.e. dynamically

Comment: have u run this? what else do u need  in it?

Comment: tr = New TableRow
   
tr.ID = "TR" + DynamicAttributeId.ToString


 
Dim tdName As New TableCell
 
tr.Cells.Add(tdName)


  

Dim tb As New TextBox
  

AddHandler tb.TextChanged, AddressOf TextChangedEvent
 
 


    
Dim btnAddNewControl As New Button
    
btnAddNewControl.ID = "btnAddNew_" + GetID(intDynamicAttributeID).ToString
    btnAddNewControl.Text = "Add New"
    
AddHandler btnAddNewControl.Click, AddressOf btnAddNew_Click

I don't understand how do i use java script to add new row